# creating formula for glmmLasso

Tags: r, statistics, glm, mixed-models

I am building a Lasso model using glmmLasso in R.

I have the equation of my model as

```
re_model <- glmmLasso(formula, rnd = list(Geography =~1 + Visits),
                       lambda=10000, data = input_data)
```

where `Geography`is a categorical variable and `Visits` is another variable in my input data.
This model is working well. 
Now I tried storing the variables `Geography` and `visits` in other variables, say `var1` and `var2`. 
Now my equation should be

```
re_model <- glmmLasso(formula, rnd = list(var1 =~1 + var2),
                       lambda=10000, data = input_data)
```

But this doesn't work. I understand this doesn't work because the model cannot find `var1` and `var2` in `input_data`. How can I accomplish this without making any change to my `dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
rnd = as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ 1 + %s", var1, var2))
```

I'm assuming that what you actually wrote in the model that worked was `rnd = Geography =~1 + Visits`, because `glmmLasso`'s help page says

> rnd: a two-sided linear formula object

?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't solve the problem. Now i am getting an error, Error in n %*% s : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: in order to sort that out we need a [mcve] please ... or at the very least the results of `str(input_data)` ...